# Post file to a remote service using the SP.WebProxy in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, office365-apps

I need help calling a remote service (outside sharepoint domain) using SP.WebProxy in a SP 2013 App.

I'm able to execute GET calls and read the response correctly, now what I'm trying to do is execute a PUT request with a BLOB/Binary file attached.

What syntax I should use? Do you have any working example about posting BLOB/Binary using SP.WebProxy?

How can I specify that the Body of SP.WebRequestInfo is a binary data??

This is the code I've written so far:

```js
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo(); 

request.set_url('http://xxxxxx.xxxx.xx/');
request.set_body(##WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE????##);
request.set_method("PUT");

var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);

context.executeQueryAsync(function () {

    console.log(response.get_statusCode());
    console.log(response.get_body());

    }, function () {
        console.log('Error Code: '++response.get_statusCode());
        console.log('Error Body: ' + response.get_body());
 });
```

Thanks and Regards

Emilio

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by binary? You mean BASE64-encoded right? Or just a blob of seemingly random characters? Or do you mean a byte array? What's the web service expecting really?

Answer (score 0):

A Web Proxy request will look something like this when sent to the REST web service URL (`YourSiteUrl/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery`):

```
<Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName="Javascript Library">
  <Actions>
    <StaticMethod TypeId="{656a77c4-1634-415c-bf85-c6c0cb286e0e}" Name="Invoke" Id="0">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter TypeId="{71aa825d-bc12-422d-a177-d2e63fe68cd9}">
          <Property Name="Body" Type="Null" />
          <Property Name="Headers" Type="Dictionary">
            <Property Name="Accept" Type="String">application/json</Property>
          </Property>
          <Property Name="Method" Type="String">GET</Property>
          <Property Name="Url" Type="String">...</Property>
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    </StaticMethod>
  </Actions>
  <ObjectPaths />
</Request>
```

The GUID `656a77c4-1634-415c-bf85-c6c0cb286e0e` is actually referencing `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebProxy` on the SPO backend, the static method `Invoke` being referenced by name. ([sparse MSDN entry here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh659469.aspx))

The GUID `656a77c4-1634-415c-bf85-c6c0cb286e0e` is a reference to the parameter type `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebRequestInfo`. ([sparse MSDN entry here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622908(v=office.12).aspx))

That last MSDN entry has info about the `Body` property ([sparse MSDN entry here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh629324.aspx)), which informs that it is in fact of type `String`.

So I think you need to encode the binary data in some way, for example by BASE64...

Comment: Hi Bjorn, this would be helpful if I could change the remote service to accept an encoded string (BASE64 for example), but I don't have control on that.

Comment: @EmilioPetrangeli Couldn't you just base64-encode it yourself and put it in there? What is the format of the data in your javascript, a string full of binary data? (then you may be able to use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa))

Comment: Just misread your comment ... well, just pasting the string of binary data won't work then? You should try posting to a server that logs the request and examine what's going wrong.